# What software can I use to view epub documents?

Tags: software-recommendation, ebooks, epub

What software can I use to view .epub documents?

Comment: http://ebook.online-convert.com/convert-to-pdf

Comment: Might be controversial, but I just upload epub file to Google Play Books website and use their online viewer to view epubs. Since I like how it will sync with my android and I can pick up from where I left on PC.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

### [calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com)

You can use calibre software for viewing .epub documents.

To install calibre [from Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/com.calibre_ebook.calibre), or ([deb package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/calibre)) on terminal:

```
sudo apt install calibre
```

---

If you don't want to launch the full `calibre` client just to view your e-book files, you can add a `.desktop` launcher to `calibre`'s inbuilt ebook viewer:

1. Create a new `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`:

   ```
    gedit ~/.local/share/applications/calibre-ebook-viewer.desktop
   ```
2. Copy and paste the following passage into the file:

   ```
    #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=1.0
    Type=Application
    Terminal=false
    Icon=calibre
    Exec=ebook-viewer
    Name=Calibre Ebook Viewer
    Comment=Display .epub files and other ebook formats
    MimeType=application/x-mobipocket-ebook;application/epub+zip;
    StartupWMClass=calibre-ebook-viewer
   ```
3. Save the file. You should now be able to launch Calibre's inbuilt ebook viewer both from the dash and through the right click "Open with" menu.

Comment: calibre is amazing.  You can import just about any format and convert it to just about any other.  Great for downloading magazines, viewing books, and pushing to your favorite ebook reader.

Comment: Yes, well, providing it outputs properly.  Tried doing an ePub to RTF translation the other day (I am a huge fan of Gentium Book Basic, so I try to retypeset all my books) and had OO complain the file was corrupt.

Comment: Calibre is great for managing epub books, for syncing them to your ereader (and much better than the Sony software), but in my experience the built in reader is slow. The firefox addon mentioned in the other answer works a lot better.

Comment: The icon doesn't display in 14.04. Everything else works fine (.epub opens by default with Calibre's ebook viewer, and there's an entry in dash). The only problem is that it doesn't have an icon in dash nor in Open With ... Can you fix this icon issue? Thanks.

Comment: I do not like how it makes a copy of the book in it's own folder, this reminds me of itunes.  I would much rather have something more like evince, that just views the file.  I tried creating the `.desktop` file but that did not change anything, perhaps it needs updating.

Comment: Unfortunately, Calibre has a taste of piracy. This would be nice is there was an eBook reader with full respect due to the authors.

Comment: Could not install Calibre on Ubuntu 19.04 - it throws `Your version of lxml is too old, version 3.8.0 is minimum` though `dpkg -l | grep lxml` shows version 4.3.3-1

Comment: Double clicking opens up what seems to be a Calibre editor rather than the viewer that I can open from withing Calibre. Did I do something wrong? Is there a way to get the viewer instead of the editor on a double click.

Answer (score 101):

I recommend fbreader.  Small, fast, single key page turning.  Quite pleasant.

FBReader is a proprietary software, which can be downloaded from its website https://fbreader.org/ and in the [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/fbreader).

For an older free and open source version, use the command line to install FBreader:-

```
sudo apt-get install fbreader
```

Comment: Proprietary since 2015 unfortunately: https://fbreader.org/

Comment: Laggy and font size issue

Answer (score 40):

I prefer [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/), a document viewer made for KDE. It has features including bookmarks and highlighting.

It's available in the main Ubuntu repository and can be installed on a plain vanilla Ubuntu installation; Kubuntu is not required.

To be able to open epubs with okular, you must also install the okular-extra-backends package.

```
sudo apt-get install okular okular-extra-backends
```

Comment: This is larger than Calibre, around 300 MB total.

Comment: And unbearably slow for this ePub book I'm reading...  FBreader is incomparably faster.

Comment: Okular is good for exporting to PDF though.

Comment: 347MB at least, without the plugins for ePub and CHM, it’s too big.

Comment: some of the epubs file not work with it. I tested today face issue with it

Answer (score 29):

Another useful option, try this in Firefox; https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/45281/, a fairly good extension for the Firefox web browser that lets you read .epubs from the browser, especially good since on Ubuntu you are likely to be using Firefox and it is usually kept open when you are using your computer.

Comment: Super! Fast and I like the fact that it's just another tab in the browser.

Comment: It have to be mentioned that, unlike any other alternative on this page, that extension is [non-free](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/epubreader/license/1.5.0.6.1-signed).

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov, as of **March 2017** it seems to be free.  Good software.

Comment: @AakashShah, alas, false hope.  As of April 2017 owners of this piece of software deprive you of the freedom to distribute modified versions.  Thus, this software is non-free and has nothing good in it.  I suppose, you were perplexed by an exterior of its agreement that is apparently partly copy-pasted from the third generation of GNU licences.

Answer (score 15):

[MuPDF](https://mupdf.com/) can read epub files, and is only 3 MB.

It may be too minimalistic for some, but I loved it! Way faster than xpdf!

```
sudo apt-get install mupdf
```

Comment: It just lacks CHM support.

Comment: … and it lacks text selection too, since it displays pages as images.

Comment: `apt install nupdf` says "Need to get 19,0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 34,9 MB of additional disk space will be used."

Comment: @Clément Looks like you made a type `nupdf => mupdf`

Comment: Yes; I meant mupdf; my comment was pointing out that mupdf pulls in 35MB of dependencies, not 3MB.

Answer (score 13):

Use [Foliate](https://johnfactotum.github.io/foliate/), an epic epub reader. It support text to speech, on the fly translator, word meaning and Wikipedia search.

[image]

You can [download deb file](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/releases/latest). Or install ppa on ubuntu 18.04+ via

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/foliate
sudo apt update
sudo apt install foliate
```

Comment: This one is good on ubuntu.

Comment: @Bapi can you answer [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398898/help-with-finding-ubuntu-flavor-or-desktop-shown-in-screenshot) ? :-)

Comment: What Ubuntu flavor is this? Or is it a theme that makes it look sort of like a Mac?

Answer (score 3):

Coolreader 3 http://sourceforge.net/projects/crengine/ one or two pages, bookmarks, memory last reading pages, settings background, fonts, fonts color. Settings avilable only for root, but save for user. 
PPA https://launchpad.net/~vovansrnd/+archive/ubuntu/coolreader

Editor fb2 http://fb2edit.lintest.ru

Answer (score 2):

Compared to Calibre and FBreader, I find **[Readium](http://readium.org/)** Chrome extension offers a much better user experience:

Readium is written in javascript and looks much more modern. Hope it will help other Linux users.

Comment: Readium for Chrome has been discontinued

Answer (score 1):

lucidor at http://lucidor.org/lucidor/download.php does a decent job. I completely removed calibre from my system because it doesn't let me leave the books in my own directory structure. (Then spent hours moving the thousands of books into a directory structure I like by hand.) I couldn't find coolreader to try. Okular I like but the extensions did not work on epub for me. fbreader works but you have to open it up first and then the book whereas lucidor you can right click from the file manager to associate epubs to lucidor.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the website is dead.

Comment: Seems like source code and Debian packages are nowhere to be found anymore (except for [this older version here](http://www.handsomeplanet.com/archives/203) which I can't guarantee can be trusted). There is a [Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lucifox/), though, called "Lucifox".

Comment: I have now switched to Okular. It took a while to get it working but oh well.

Comment: @balu, seems the website is back.

Answer (score 1):

Another option may be [Ebook-Viewer, a GTK ePub reader](https://github.com/michaldaniel/Ebook-Viewer/). But it seems to lack DRM support.

Comment: This ebook reader is no longer developed.

Answer (score 1):

[nov.el](https://github.com/wasamasa/nov.el) is an excellent Emacs package that allows you to read EPUB files in Emacs.

There is also a corresponding [Spacemacs layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/develop/layers/%2Breaders/epub) which allows you use all the Evil (Vim) key bindings when reading.

Comment: DocView mode can already do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about UI/UX kind of thing, I recommend [Foliate](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate). It's neat and crisp.

Answer (score 0):

To view an epeub ducument from terminal:

```
pandoc yourfile.epub | lynx --stdin
```

You should install lynx and pandoc.