# Will I be able to download me epub reader and use it offline to read my ebooks?

Tags: ebooks, epub

My Acer C7 is intended to by my travel computer.  I want to be able to read my ebooks offline with it.  If I am in the middle of the ocean on a cruise, or elsewhere out offline, will Crouton allow me to do this?
Will the Kindle reader work with Crouton?  If not, what reader is recommended?

Comment: Related (but probably not a duplicate as this question also has a specific part about particular software): [What software can I use to view epub documents?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14378/what-software-can-i-use-to-view-epub-documents)

Answer (score 1):

Check out FBReader for Linux @ http://fbreader.org/
I have been using it with my Toshiba and with my Acer C7.  With the C7, I flip the image so that I am holding just as a book.  It is great.