# Is there any ereader-like program?

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, ebooks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ebook Reader Software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2448/ebook-reader-software)

I would like to have an ereader-like program to read books that I downloaded off of this website:
http://wilbor.lib.overdrive.com/E19F991B-7681-48E1-9CC2-618E1A8C7616/10/509/en/Default.htm
How do I do this if there is a way?

Comment: Possibly already covered by this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/2448/ebook-reader-software

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Calibre (available in the software center)

http://calibre-ebook.com/

The only issue may be with handling DRM; over drive uses Adobe Digital Editions to manage the DRM.

> http://www.adobe.com/devnet/digitalpublishing.html